# Why can't I store OWL class in a Variable?

Tags: prolog, owl, swi-prolog

I am not sure where exactly my problem or misunderstanding is. I am using OWL within Knowrob and Rosprolog.

In my OWL, `hsr_objects:'Banana'` is a subclass of `hsr_objects:'Item'`. So this behaves as expected:

```
?- owl_subclass_of(hsr_objects:'Banana', hsr_objects:'Item')
true.
```

But why does the error occur in the following prompt?

```
?- X=hsr_objects:'Banana', owl_subclass_of(X, hsr_objects:'Item')
Prolog query failed: error(type_error(rdf_object,hsr_objects:Banana),context(rdf_db:rdf_has/3,_434))
```